# Encoded base64 public key in c# and decode base64 in java

Tags: java, c#, base64, public-key

What is the right way to encode a public key using base64 in C#, save to file, and after read that file in java and recompute the key.

This in C#

```
File.WriteAllText(System.Convert.ToBase64String(certificate.GetPublicKey()))
```

In Java, I read all bytes and after I tried this:

```
PublicKey pubKey = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(Base64.getDecoder().decode(bytesFromFile)))
```

And it throws

> invalid key format

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking - is the problem around using base64, or handling a key in both C# and Java? Base64 is just a way of encoding arbitrary binary data as text.

Comment: Well, whatever the right way is, this obviously isn't. Did you read [ask]? Please show what you have tried. At the Moment, it seems you didn't try anything. Where are you stuck? You could start with providing a [mcve].

Comment: Sorry is first time when i post. i Edited my post. Is not all my code , but I minimized the main idea.

Comment: Still not a lot to go on. Separate the 2 problems: check the length and the contents (a few bytes at start and/or end) of the byte array in C# and then do the same in Java. When you are able to convey the binary data correctly, start solving the key/encryption problem.

Comment: The idea is that the bytes returned by method GetPublicKey() are not recognise correctly by X509EncodedKeySpec() constructor. I tested and are same bytes from an application to another.

Comment: Solved. The idea is that the java byte is different from the one in c #. In java the byte representation is with sign and the one in the c # is unsigned.

Answer (score 0):

### Encode in C#:

```
@using System;
@using System.Text;

string password = "yourpassword";
 var passwordBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);
 string encodedPassword = Convert.ToBase64String(passwordBytes);
 //Debug.Write("csEncodedPassword: "+csEncodedPassword);
```

### Decode in Java:

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.StringUtils;

String decodedPass = java.net.URLDecoder.decode(csEncodedPassword,StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
String decoded64pass= StringUtils.newStringUtf8(Base64.decodeBase64(decodedPass));
```